# OfficeJS Excel Keyboard Shortcuts Not Working

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins

I have done everything in the documentation

- Manifest, Webpack, Associate, Shortcuts.json file

Everything is exactly as it should. No keyboard shortcut seems to be working.

I am on a windows laptop.

I build the add-in, the functions work, but the shortcuts related to the functions don't do anything.

Any thoughts on things I should check for? Thanks

Comment: Please show your `manifest` and `webpack` and `shortcuts.json` etc so we can actually help. I struggled very hard to get my `combo` Add-In to work, but I did eventually get an Add-In that had `commands`/`taskpane`/`shortcuts`/`custom functions` all working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether keyboard shortcuts are supported by your host application. Keyboard shortcuts are currently only supported on Excel and only on these platforms and builds:

- Excel on Windows: Version 2102 (Build 13801.20632) and later
- Excel on Mac: 16.48 and later
- Excel on the web

Also keyboard shortcuts work only on platforms that support the following requirement sets.

- SharedRuntime 1.1
- KeyboardShortcuts 1.1

For more about requirement sets and how to work with them, see [Specify Office applications and API requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements).

Finally, you need to make sure that you did everything like described in the [Add custom keyboard shortcuts to your Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/keyboard-shortcuts) article.